# Using a jqueryui dialog, I'm trying to focus on a textarea but the cursor never appears

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, focus, textarea, blur

I'm using

- jquery : 1.9.1
- jqueryui : 1.10.2
- all browsers show the same behaviour -

So I'm launching a jquery dialog anytime someone right-clicks a textarea element.  I noticed that the textarea is getting focus with an active cursor when it gets right-clicked, so I call blur() on the element to get rid of the cursor.

Works, no problem.

Then in the dialog, if the user clicks "edit" I want to put the cursor back active on the text area.  I call show(), and focus() [see code below], but it doesn't get the focus back.  No errors, just nothing happens besides the dialog closing which is what I want (dialog closes, textarea should have an active cursor but doesn't).

Below is the code, any help very appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours.  I identified the code I expect to work but doesn't with "THIS IS THE PROBLEM"

## HTML

This is the element that is a jqueryui dialog.  When the user right-clicks the target element, this shows up as the content of the dialog

```
<div id="popupDialog">
    <input type="button" id="editRowButton" class="contextmenuButton"
           value="edit">
</div>
```

Throughout the page I have these textareas that when right-clicked, will show the jqueryui dialog.

```
<textarea id="targetThatWasRightClicked" >some content in the textarea</textarea>
```

## javascript

```
<!-- This handler is used to clear the dialog if anyone clicks outside the dialog.-->
<!-- Is working fine. -->
$(document).bind('click',function(){
    // if the dialog is open, close it
    if( $("#popupDialog").dialog("isOpen" ) ) {
        closeDialog();
    }
});


function closeDialog() {
    mydialog.target = null;
    $("#popupDialog").dialog("close" ); <!-- invokes the jquery close method. --> 
                                        <!-- This is working fine -->
};


<!-- is used to initialize the jqueryui dialog, also holds a reference to the -->
<!-- object that gets right-clicked as "target". -->
var mydialog = { 
    target : null,

    init : function() {
        $('#popupDialog').dialog({
            modal: true,
            dialogClass: "no-close",
            width:'auto',
            height:'auto',
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen: false
        });
}


<!-- general setup stuff when the $(document).ready(..) function is called. -->
function initSideMenu() {

    $("#editRowButton" ).button();

    $('#editRowButton').click( function() {

        <!-- THIS IS THE PROBLEM: I expect the textarea (the target) to have -->
        <!-- a blinking cursor in it after these next two commands, but it  -->
        <!-- remains unselected. -->
        mydialog.target.show();
        mydialog.target.focus();

        closeDialog();
    });

    mydialog.init();


    $("#targetThatWasRightClicked").on("contextmenu", function(e){

        var target = $(e.target);

        <!-- the right-click focussed on the textarea, so un-focus it so the -->
        <!-- cursor isn't blinking in the textarea. -->
        target.blur();

        <!-- set "target" = the right-clicked element and open a dialog box -->
        mydialog.target = target;
        $('#popupDialog').dialog('open');

        e.preventDefault();  <!-- So the browser's contextmenu doesn't appear. -->
        e.stopPropagation(); <!-- So the document click handler doesn't get called -->
                             <!-- and close the dialog. -->
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to close dialog before focus:

```
    mydialog.target.show();
    closeDialog(); 
    mydialog.target.focus();
```

Comment: Wow, awesome. That didn't quite do it, since the closeDialog() makes mydialog.target = null, but I added this temp pointer and it worked:       'var temp = mydialog.target;
     mydialog.target.show();
     closeDialog();
     temp.focus();'

Comment: Just wondering, what was the reasoning behind that?  I thought the dialog and the textarea were independent?

Comment: yeah, i missed this particular :) the important thing is to leave the focus() as last action

Comment: probably when you call $("#popupDialog").dialog("close" ); the cursor move in another position!